# `graphdrawing` - One `phylogenetics` example fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

The following example comes from the PGF documentation (see page 485).

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{phylogenetics}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph[phylogenetic tree layout,
       upgma,
       distance matrix = {
        0 4 9 9 9 9 9 
        4 0 9 9 9 9 9
        9 9 0 2 7 7 7 
        9 9 2 0 7 7 7 
        9 9 7 7 0 3 5 
        9 9 7 7 3 0 5
        9 9 7 7 5 5 0 }]
{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g }; 

\end{document}
```

This gives...

[image]

Instead of

[image: XXXX]

Is it a bug or is there a missing configuration in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No bug, the style of the nodes is determined by the `/graph drawing/phylogenetic inner node` style. This is by default empty, but *in the manual* it is defined as described in the section immediately following the example:

[image]

Copy the `\pgfgdset{..}` to your preamble to get the same output as in the manual.

Comment: The documentation should have put it in the 1st example. Thanks for this!

Comment: @projetmbc I suppose. There has been a lot of work done with regard to making the examples in the manual complete though. In particular including all necessary libraries I think, but perhaps style definitions as well. See https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/640

Comment: I have added a message on github.